# Hide/Show a button after clicking Asp.Net

Tags: asp.net, web-applications

I have a button on a page that creates a PDF of the page. I would like to hide the button for the pdf then show it after the pdf is created. I tried the following in codebehind and it does not hide the button.

```
Private Sub PdfPageButton_ServerClick(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles PdfPageButton.ServerClick
    PdfPageButton.Visible = False
    ConvertURLToPDF()
    PdfPageButton.Visible = True
End Sub

Private Sub ConvertURLToPDF()
    Dim urlToConvert As String = HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.AbsoluteUri

    'more code here not displayed...   

    ' Performs the conversion and get the pdf document bytes that you can further 
    ' save to a file or send as a browser response
    Dim pdfBytes As Byte() = pdfConverter.GetPdfBytesFromUrl(urlToConvert)

    ' send the PDF document as a response to the browser for download
    Dim Response As System.Web.HttpResponse = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Response
    Response.Clear()
    Response.AddHeader("Content-Type", "binary/octet-stream")
    Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=ConversionResult.pdf; size=" & pdfBytes.Length.ToString())
    Response.Flush()
    Response.BinaryWrite(pdfBytes)
    Response.Flush()
    Response.End()
End Sub
```

However I use [@media print] in css to not display my print button. to bad it doesn't work in other ways

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason it doesn't hide the button is because the page doesn't get rendered again before this line:

```
PdfPageButton.Visible = True
```

If it were WinForms, your approach would work but on the web you need to do it a bit differently.

You could hide the button by simply setting a CSS style of `display:none` in the button's `onclick()` event:

```
<input type="button" id="pdfBtn" onclick="this.style.display = 'none';" />
```

but to show it again when the PDF has been generated, you'd either need to refresh the page in its entirety (i.e. a postback), or you could wire up an event listener if you wanted to use AJAX.

**EDIT:** Given the extra info that the PDF is of the page itself, could you perhaps add a querystring parameter to the URL, e.g.

`mysite/mypage.aspx?isPDF=1`

Then, in your `PageLoad()`, add:

```
if(Request.QueryString["isPDF"] == "1")
{
    PdfButton.Visible == false;
}
```

so that the button doesn't exist when `isPDF` is set to '1' (or whatever you choose).

Then, pass *that* URL with the extra param to the `ConvertURLToPDF()` method?

Comment: You are correct, it did hide the button but its still showed up on the pdf.

Comment: Oh right - the PDF is a PDF _of the current page_? We'd need to know how it's being generated, but I suggest you search for using CSS with media="print"

Comment: Your a genius that worked awsome. I added this... Dim urlToConvert As String = HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.AbsoluteUri & "?IsPdf=1" and Query string to the PageLoad event and Wa La it worked. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

if you want to hide button in web browser, You must use javascript. VBA is server side language like php. You need make a ajax call to make pdf.
When user clicks on button, trigger action with javascript, hide button, send request to server, wait for answer and then display button again.

Comment: In other words use a __doPostBack in javascript function?

Comment: It is based on what javascript framework you use. 
here is ajax example http://www.codeproject.com/KB/ajax/AjaxASPdotNET.aspx

Answer (score 1):

This will hide the button on the client side when you click the button. Then, when your page renders a response, the button should be displayed again.

```
<asp:Button ID="PdfPageButton" OnClientClick="document.getElementById('PdfPageButton').style.display = 'none';" />
```

Comment: @Bandon thanks for reply, i added the markup to my button but unfortunately i did not hide the button.

Answer (score 0):

It is hiding it, and then showing it, but it won't show to the client because all this is happening in the code-behind before the Page is rendered to the user.

Your best bet would be to add some client side script to hide the button when they click it. When the page is regenerated, the button would be there again, visible to them.